# Facebook Comment integration iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, comments

Does anyone has already succeeded integrating facebook comments in iOS ?

I am making an app for a blog and I *simply* want to integrate facebook comment

I tried the UIWebView way, but it doesn't show anything in iOS 6. I tried a lot of thing to make it work, but I stopped when I saw that it doesn't show up in the web view of the twitter app.

I also tried to integrate the SDK, although it's impossible to publish comment (error from the api), I tried at least to retrieve all the comment attached to an URL, but as it's not possible to join table in FQL, I would have to,for each comment, retrieve informations about the user that has posted the comment... Silly !!

Am I the only one Facebook cursed ?

Comment: Ok this is really annoying, can't find a solution that works !

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to do this either so at least two of us are cursed. It would be great if facebook allowed you to use the facebook comment box to comment on facebook posts.  I for one do not find working with the facebook API documentation very helpful.